# Checkbox does not posts values upon styling

Tags: python, html, checkbox

Well, I used [this link](http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/) to style the checkboxes. Now, when I try to get the values of those checked boxes, I get NULL. But, when I doesn't use that library, I get the expected outputed. Any thoughts Why and how can I deal with it?

Here's how I'm getting the values of Checked Boxes :

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    selected_users = request.POST.getlist('users')
    print selected_users
```

**Form**

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" class="myClass" value="1"  name="users"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="myClass" value="2"  name="users"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="myClass" value="3"  name="users"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="myClass" value="4"  name="users"/>

</form>
```

Comment: i dont think youve presented enough info here. getlist('users') seems to have nothing to do with the checkboxes below.

Comment: As _seth_ mentioned, try `name="users"` instead of `name="answer"`.

Comment: oops soory.....the `name` field has the value `users`. Question updated.

Comment: I actually copied it from the site itself. Forgot to update it over here. Though my personal code contains `users` only. Apology

Comment: I think you are saying that the 3 lines of python you have in your question description are irrelevant so need to be removed and replaced with ... javascript?

Comment: No. They are correct. When I dont apply styling to the checkboxes, they work fine.